# Creating a custom progress bar indicator in Spark Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, visualization, azure-databricks

I would like to create a custom progress bar for a job I am running in pyspark Azure Databricks. I tried doing this using matplotlib by creating multiple figures and calling display one by one for each but the output is displayed only when the entire job completes so it's not much of a progress bar.

Is there a simple way to create such a display that also gets updated as progress is being made?

Thanks for your help.

[the spark databricks default progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Kre.png)

Comment: This feature is already available in Azure Databricks: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/23/easier-spark-code-debugging-real-time-progress-bar-and-apache-spark-web-ui-integration-in-databricks.html

Comment: Yes, of-course but I am talking about the webui that you after running a cell in databricks. I would like to replace it with something that is more meaningful in my context.

Comment: @RoyLevin I was wondering if you were able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "displayHTML" function in order to render a custom progress bar through embedded CSS/JavaScript. This works as "displayHTML" will reset the cell output everytime you call it (just make sure you call sleep for a few seconds between each call, so you can see how the output changes), however you will also need to update all the rest of the output in each call

Comment: This behaviour is changed as of [DBR v7.1](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/product/2020/july.html#python-notebooks-now-support-multiple-outputs-per-cell). Now repeated calls to the "displayHTML" function add new HTML displays to the cell output rather than resetting the cell output. Release notes also mention that this behaviour is controlled with "spark.databricks.workspace.multipleResults.enabled" configuration, but changing it to "false" didn't work for me. Besides, the issue still persists with the output is being displayed when the entire job completes.